# rest api examples other than crud operations on lists

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest

I have tried learning rest using the basic examples.But I could not get any other  rest example samples other than the CRUD operations on lists.
Can anyone provide me the suggestions where i can get the rest api examples other than crud operations on lists

Comment: What other operations besides Create, Read, Update and Delete would you want to do on a List?

Comment: While searching for rest api examples am getting the crud operations on lists only.Other than those anywhere can i get rest api examples

Comment: But WHAT other operations do you want? CRUD are all the operations you can do on a List: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx

Comment: Use can use REST Search API also to search across site collections n all..You can create web, get web properties, etc. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: A basic google search should reveal all the different things you can do with REST.  Anything advanced, such as managing user permissions, you need to specify.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best place to start: [REST API reference and samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx). These pages contain documentation and samples that go far beyond performing CRUD operations on lists.

I also have a course in the Pluralsight library entitled [SharePoint 2013 Development: Client Object Model and REST API](http://www.shareasale.com/r.cfm?u=1242771&b=611266&m=53701&afftrack=&urllink=www%2Epluralsight%2Ecom%2Fcourses%2Fsharepoint%2D2013%2Dclient%2Dobject%2Dmodel%2Drest). This course covers how to work with documents, managed metadata, user permissions, search, and more. You can get a free trial subscription to check out the course if you are not already a subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a "SharePoint REST Tester" to help learn and test the SharePoint REST APIs on my own site without writing testing code. While in no way complete, it does have over 80 examples or REST calls. After testing a call, it can display the returned data, an example of a JQuery AJAX call and steps to duplicate the call in a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow.

The project has examples for Search, CAML Queryies, List Items/Documents, Lists/Libraries, Folders, Recycle Bins, Site Collections, Webs, User Profiles, Permissions, and even a few SP 2010 API examples.

The project is here: https://github.com/microsmith/SharePointRESTtester

The blog article for it is here: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2017/04/a-sharepoint-rest-api-tester-with-ajax.html

And as a note to self... I need to update the github files as I have about 10-20 more examples to add.